# How to add page category slug to base url

Tags: pages, url-rewriting

I use `register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'page' );` to add a taxonomy to the Page, but the url doesn't show the page's category slug.

So is there any way to display the slug of the current category of the Page like:

```
domain.com/page-cat1/page1

domain.com/page-cat2/page2
```

Comment: How is your URL currently structured? Have you taken a look at the "Permalinks" page in Settings?

Comment: @YourManDan My current permalink setting: `/%category%/%postname%/` , seem like category's slug not working on Page post type

Comment: There's not enough information here to work with yet, please revise your answer with your full relevant code for your `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` function and the location you put the code in. Ensure you're using the proper `add_action` call as outlined [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy_for_object_type/#user-contributed-notes).